# How can I shift page images in PDF files more to the left or to the right?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We have a bunch of scanned pages (about 600) for which every PDF viewer displays the image with zero margin on the right edge, but about 2 inch margin on the left. (Presumably while scanning, there was a wrong setting used...)

We want to print these pages, preferably as a booklet. Is there a way to permanently shift all page images towards the center and have the PDF display these pages also in a more pleasing way? Can Ghostscript do that? Can one do this with some other method, such as programatically with the help of some PDF processing library?

Comment: This is not a programming question and would benefit from being moved to SuperUser.

Comment: @Robino I'm sorry, is postscript not a programming language?

Comment: @ebyrob The goal is to alter a PDF in a specific way. It is not about programming, even though there is a solution using a programming language.

Comment: @Robino By that logic, walking on the moon is not related to orbital mechanics.  PS - PDF (though compressed and obfuscated) is also basically a programming language.  Certainly we wouldn't expect users to understand *.doc format better than programmers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want to write your own program code (as Nikolaus suggested), but use a Ghostscript commandline instead, you need to know 3 things:

1. PostScript has a `setpagedevice` operator that takes a `PageOffset` parameter;
2. Ghostscript will process snippets of PostScript code if you pass them with `-c ...` on the commandline;
3. Ghostscript can evaluate and apply (some) *PostScript* code even for direct *PDF=>PDF* conversions.

Now try this commandline to shift all page images by 1 inch (==72pt) to the left:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -o c:/path/to/output/pdf-shifted-by-1-inch-to-left.pdf ^
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
  -c "<</PageOffset [-72 0]>> setpagedevice" ^
  -f c:/path/to/input/pdf-original.pdf
```

<sub>(The `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` I put in in order to not loose any picture quality of the scans...)</sub>

Comment: I've got a new problem now. It is about font extracting. I'll ask a separate question about this.

Comment: @Community: **NO** -- Ghostscript does **not** require the backslashes instead of the forward slashes. You can keep them as they are and it will work the same. (Doesn't hurt to change to backslashes though... however, you may need to change to **double** backslashes for some versions even...) And **NO**, you don't need to change hyphens (`-`) to forward slash (`/`) -- that one can even hurt! I'll revert your modification, sorry!

Comment: I got error `**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.` while launching this command. Any idea ?

Comment: @Stéphane: is your `-o ...` parameter pointing to an output directory where you do not own the privilege to write into?

Comment: Hum no that's /tmp pointing to ... Anyway I endeded using convert command, which is not perfect. And I modified my original odt document to add margin. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use iText to move, scale or crop pdf-pages

you need to define a PdfReader for your source file, and a Document for your Target file
then you iterate over the pages if the Reader, create a new page in the Document
and add the sourcePage as a Template to the new page (shifting, scaling etc wherever you want)

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader( input );
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

    Rectangle psize = reader.getPageSize(1);
    float width = psize.getHeight();
    float height = psize.getWidth();

    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(height, width));
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream( output ));

    document.open();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        i++;
        document.newPage();
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        cb.addTemplate(page, factor, 0, 0, factor, left, down);
    }

    document.close();
```

Comment: Nice and powerful approach. Just meanwhile I'll go for the free fork in https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF