# How do you shift all pages of a PDF document right by one inch?

Tags: c++, python, linux, pdf, pypdf

I want to shift all the pages of an existing pdf document right one inch so they can be three hole punched without hitting the content.  The pdf documents will be already generated so changing the way they are generated is not possible.

It appears iText can do this from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447720/how-can-i-shift-page-images-in-pdf-files-more-to-the-left-or-to-the-right).

What is an equivalent library (or way do this) for C++ or Python?

If it is platform dependent I need one that would work on Linux.

**Update:** Figured I would post a little script I wrote to do this in case anyone else finds this page and needs it.

Working code thanks to Scott Anderson's suggestion:

rightshift.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys
import os
from  pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

#not sure what default user space units are. 
# just guessed until current document i was looking at worked
uToShift = 50;

if (len(sys.argv) < 3):
  print "Usage rightshift [in_file] [out_file]"
  sys.exit()

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
  print "%s does not exist." % sys.argv[1]
  sys.exit()

pdfInput = PdfFileReader(file( sys.argv[1], "rb"))
pdfOutput = PdfFileWriter()

pages=pdfInput.getNumPages()

for i in range(0,pages):
  p = pdfInput.getPage(i)
  for box in (p.mediaBox, p.cropBox, p.bleedBox, p.trimBox, p.artBox):
    box.lowerLeft = (box.getLowerLeft_x() - uToShift, box.getLowerLeft_y())
    box.upperRight = (box.getUpperRight_x() - uToShift, box.getUpperRight_y())
  pdfOutput.addPage( p )

outputStream = file(sys.argv[2], "wb")
pdfOutput.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: How heavy is your monitor?

Comment: You move the paper guides on you printer left one inch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) library. In 2022 PyPDF2 was merged back into pypdf.

Comment: Less dependencies than LaTeX solutions.  Is a library for python as question asked. Changed to correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

two ways to perform this task in **Linux**

1. using **ghostscript** trough **gsview**

   - look in your **/root** or **/home** for the hidden file **.gsview.ini**
   - go to section:

   > **[pdfwrite Options]**
   >
   > Options=
   >
   > Xoffset=0
   >
   > Yoffset=0

change the values for X axis, settling a convenient value (values are in postscript points, **1 inch** = **72 postscript points**)

so:

> **[pdfwrite Options]**
>
> Options=
>
> Xoffset=72
>
> Yoffset=0

- close **.gsview.ini**
- open your pdf file with **gsview**
- **file / convert / pdfwrite**
- select first **odd** pages and print to a new file (you can name this as **odd.pdf**)

now repeat same steps for even pages

- open your pdf file with **gsview**

> **[pdfwrite Options]**
>
> Options=
>
> Xoffset=-72
>
> Yoffset=0

- **file / convert / pdfwrite**
- select first **even** pages and print to a new file (you can name this as **even.pdf**)

now you need to mix these two pdf with odd and even pages

you can use:

**Pdf Transformer**

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-transformer/

`java -jar ./pdf-transformer-0.4.0.jar <INPUT_FILE_NAME1>  <INPUT_FILE_NAME2> <OUTPUT_FILE_NAME> merge -j`

---

**2:** : use **podofobox** + **pdftk**

- first step: with **pdftk** separate whole pdf document in two pdf files with only **odd** and **even** pages

  `pdftk file.pdf cat 1-endodd output odd.pdf && pdftk file.pdf cat 1-endeven output even.pdf`
- now with **podofobox**, included into **podofo utils**
- http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html
- `podofobox file.pdf odd.pdf crop -3600 0 widht height` for **odd pages** and
- `podofobox file.pdf even.pdf crop 3600 0 widht height` for **even pages**

*width and height are in postscript point x 100 and can be found with **pdfinfo***

**e.g.** if your pdf file has pagesize **482x680**, then you enter

`./podofobox file.pdf odd.pdf crop -3600 0 48200 68000`

`./podofobox file.pdf even.pdf crop 3600 0 48200 68000`

then you can mix together odd and even in a unique file with already cited

**Pdf Transformer**

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-transformer/

Comment: +1 for mentioning odd and even will be shifted different directions

Answer (score 3):

With `pdfjam`, the command to translate all pages 1 inch to the right is

```
pdfjam --offset '1in 0in' doc.pdf
```

The transformed document is saved to `doc-pdfjam.pdf`.  For further options, type `pdfjam --help`.  Currently `pdfjam` requires a Unix-like command prompt (Linux, Mac, or Cygwin).  In Ubuntu, it can be installed with

```
sudo apt install pdfjam
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but you can use LaTeX with pdfpages:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/

Multiple commandline linux tools also use this approach, for instance pdfjam uses this:
http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam

Maybe pdfjam can already provide what you need already.

Comment: Looks like a lot of dependencies and a large learning curve. An external call to pdfjam looks like the way to go. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: If you don't know LaTeX it is ;) However, LaTeX is a good tool to have in your toolbox imho. It's great for creating pdfs fast from a text source. And the dependencies don't trouble me as much in linux as the do in windows/macosx. You can just apt-get the lot, and it works. But glad this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version for python3.x.

**First install pypdf2 via `pip install pypdf2`**

```
import sys
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

uToShift = 40; # amount to shift contents by. +ve shifts right

if (len(sys.argv) < 3):
  print ("Usage rightshift [in_file] [out_file]")
  sys.exit()

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
  print ("%s does not exist." % sys.argv[1])
  sys.exit()

path=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open(("%s\\%s" % (path, sys.argv[1])), "rb") as pdfin:
    with open(("%s\\%s" % (path, sys.argv[2])), "wb") as pdfout:
        pdfInput = PdfFileReader(pdfin)
        pdfOutput = PdfFileWriter()

        pages=pdfInput.getNumPages()

        for i in range(0,pages):
          p = pdfInput.getPage(i)
          for box in (p.mediaBox, p.cropBox, p.bleedBox, p.trimBox, p.artBox):
            box.lowerLeft = (box.getLowerLeft_x() - uToShift, box.getLowerLeft_y())
            box.upperRight = (box.getUpperRight_x() - uToShift, box.getUpperRight_y())
          pdfOutput.addPage( p )

        pdfOutput.write(pdfout)
```