# Using ghostscript as x11 viewer (gs x11 viewport positioning)?

Tags: x11, ghostscript, viewer

I already know about [Ghostscript front end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript#Front_ends) viewers; but I was wondering how `gs` itself could be used for viewing PDF documents?

The closest I could get to, is to specify explicitly `x11` window as output device, specify width and height of the window via `-g`, and specify rasterization resolution via `-r`; or, a command line like this:

```
gs -sDevice=x11 -g500x500 -r150x150 -dFirstPage=3 fontspec.pdf
```

... which results with something like:

[image: ghostscript-viewing.png]

... which is, in fact, all good - except, it starts at lower left corner; and there are no keyboard shortcuts (as far as I can see) here to move the viewport, or to perform some zooming.

I'm aware that `ghostscipt` probably doesn't have mouse/keyboard interaction for navigating a x11 window output, given that something like that is reserved for front-end viewers like `gv`. So, the closest thing to that (for me) in ghostscript would be - how to render a specific region of a page? Via `-d` and `-r` the most important parameters are already specified - I'd just want to, say, specify a different point than 0x0 (say, x=100 y=100) as a lower left corner when viewing.

(*In other words, I'd like to say to `ghostscript`: show page 3 of document.pdf, rasterized at 150x150, in a window of 500x500, starting from lower-left corner x,y=100,100*).

How can this be done in `ghostscript`? Are there command line switches for that - or would one have to use `postscript` language commands in terminal, once `ghostscript` has loaded?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Not sure this is a programming question, at all ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @unwind - I think it has aspects of a programming question, in that one cannot understand why `gs` isn't really a viewer, unless one understands it as a PostScript language interpreter (which I often forget); but otherwise I wouldn't have a problem with the post being moved to say SuperUser... Cheers! (PS: edited title too)

Comment: @sdaau postscript is a programming language and the question: "What is the post-script command to move the text when printing." is certainly a programming question.  That said, I very much like the extra detail about what you're really trying to do and the same question has been bothering me for a while.  Good Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK, Ghostscript itself doesn't provide what you want (a 'viewport'). That's exactly what the ghostview and gv GUI frontends are for.

Ghostscript treats the x11 device (almost) as a print page output device, and print pages do have fixed sizes, and you cannot move a 'viewport' of the page image on them either -- unless you do re-print them with a different setting: and this is then where a differently valued  `-c "<</PageOffset [-150 133]>> setpagedevice"` parameter comes into play...

Answer (score 2):

OK, thanks to [(#277826) ghostscript - How can I shift page images in PDF files more to the left or to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483621/277826), I can see there is possibility to use `postscript`'s `PageOffset` command/operator to achieve offset/displacement of the viewport; thus the following command line can be used:

```
gs -sDevice=x11 -g500x500 -r150x150 -dFirstPage=3 -c '<</PageOffset [-150 133]>> setpagedevice' -f fontspec.pdf
```

Note that, unlike the command line in OP - here you *must* use the `-f` switch to specify the input file here - if not, the command will fail with: `Error: /undefined in fontspec.pdf`.

Otherwise, the output looks like this:

[image: ghostscript-view-offset.png]

So this is nice to know - but I'm still curious if `ghostscript` doesn't already have some default switches, that would allow this viewport offset/repositioning thing...

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: AFAIK, Ghostscript itself doesn't provide what you want. That's what the `ghostview` and `gv` GUI frontends are for. Ghostscript treats the x11 device (almost) as a print page output device, and print pages do have fixed sizes, and you cannot move a 'viewport' of the page image on them either without re-printing them with a different setting.   :-)

Comment: Hey @pipitas - many thanks for your comment; that is exactly the kind of confirmation I was looking for! Actually, I think your comment answers the OP question better; so if you feel like it, please make an answer from this comment - I'll accept it (and then this answer posting of mine can remain as supplement, for reference). Thanks again - cheers!