# How to scale down the content of a pdf page per page using ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Hi I'm wondering how I can scale down / resize a pdf content page per page and my pages could have different size and orientation. My expected result would be a A4 page with the content that best fit to it.

Based on these topics:

- [How to resize content of PDF without affecting page size?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343179/how-to-resize-content-of-pdf-without-affecting-page-size/343247#343247)
- [Using GhostScript to get page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943281/using-ghostscript-to-get-page-size/52644056#52644056)
- [How to make per-page changes to a pdf document using Ghostscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618020)

I written a simple code but since I'm really begin with this it is probably not the way to do it.

```js
const script = `
FileName (r) file                 % open file given by -sFileName
runpdfbegin                       % open file as pdf
1 1 pdfpagecount {                % for each page index
  pdfgetpage                      % get pdf page properties (pushes a dict)
  /MediaBox get                   % get MediaBox value from dict (pushes an array of numbers [ offsetX offsetY width height ])

  % Define the new expected height & width
  /nheight ${newHeight} def
  /nwidth ${newWidth} def


  % Destruct the array to the stack
  aload pop
  /pheight exch def
  /pwidth exch def
  pop pop
  
  % Compute scales
  nheight pheight div         % compute scale ratio of height
  nwidth pwidth div           % compute scale ratio of width

  % Now we have the two scale ratio

  1 index 1 index lt
  {                               % if scaleY < scaleX
    pop
  }
  {
    exch
    pop
  }
  ifelse
  /pscale exch def
  
  % At this stage I have the min scale
  
  % Compute translateX
  pwidth pscale pwidth % (WIDTH - (scale * WIDTH)) / 2
  mul sub 2 div round
  /ptranslateX exch def
  
  % Compute translateY
  pheight pscale pheight % (HEIGHT - (scale * HEIGHT)) / 2
  mul sub 2 div round
  /ptranslateY exch def
  
  % Now build the scale and translate operation
  <</BeginPage{pscale pscale scale ptranslateX ptranslateY translate}>> setpagedevice
} for`

  //  Resize the page
  await spawnProcess('gs', [
    '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite',
    '-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook',
    '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.5',
    '-dSubsetFonts=true',
    '-dEmbedAllFonts=true',
    '-dFIXEDMEDIA',
    '-dSAFER',
    '-dNOPAUSE',
    '-dBATCH',
    '-dUNROLLFORMS',
    '-dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage',
    '-dFitPage',
    `-sOutputFile=${filename}-resized.pdf`,
    `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595`,
    `-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842`,
    // '-c', `<</BeginPage{${scale} ${scale} scale ${translateX} ${translateY} translate}>> setpagedevice`,
    '-c', script,
    '-sFileName', filename
  ])
```

Note: Using ghostscript `-dFitPage` option works on some pdf but not all of them in contrary to `-c "<</BeginPage{${scale} ${scale} scale ${translateX} ${translateY} translate}>> setpagedevice"` that works on all the pdfs I tested but does not fit page per page. That's why I'm trying to do a custom script.

It would be great if you could help me to be on the right way

Comment: I have, basically, left Stack Overflow; too many run-ins with moderators who are not amenable to reason IMO. If you want to talk to the Ghostscript developers your best bet is the #ghostscript channel on the Artifex server on Discord, or the #ghostscript channel on the Libera IRC server. We used to be on #ghostscript on the Freenode server, but that has recently become non-viable, sadly. Or you can raise bug reports, of course, or subscribe and post to the gs-devel mailing list.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your useful suggestions, I'm gonna look at discord and will update my post with the final solution for others who have the same issue ;)