# Ghostscript: Resize Letter (612 x 712 pts) to A4 (595 x 842 pts)

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=outputA4.pdf LETTER.pdf
```

This gives me page size of 595 x 770 pts. How can I change the height to match 842 pts? Or how can I add that 72 pts padding to bottom of the page?

Comment: I doubt you are getting an output with a media size of 595x770 points, how are you determining that size ? Of course, without an example file to look at it's impossible to duplicate your work. There are other questions which more or less duplicate yours, and have answers, here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618020/how-to-make-per-page-changes-to-a-pdf-document-using-ghostscript

Comment: I checked page sizes with pdfinfo command. Output file is 595 x 770pts. Yea I will check other discussions thanks!

Comment: So the problem is that output.pdf file has width of A4 but keeps ratio from LETTER so the height isn´t right.

Comment: Again, it's pretty much impossible to help you without an example file to look at. What you are saying doesn't make any sense to me, I can't see how that would happen. That doesn't mean I'm saying you're wrong, but if I can't understand it, I can't suggest anything to help.